# Is there any way to interrupt autocomplete in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

So while I am writing some code in lisp, autocomplete frequently hangs for one or two seconds (depends on connection to repl) and during this period of time emacs doesn't show what I am typing. You are typing and nothing happens, then all characters appear.

There is a delay that you can adjust not to start completion at all if you are typing fast. You can type very slowly and completion delay won't annoy you.

I am wondering is there a way to make user interation be more prioritized then autocomplete thread. When you are typing at the same time as autocomplete works could your input action interrupt it?

Comment: Does hitting `C-g` work? This probably is highly dependent on what is providing the autcompletion